# In Excel, how to create report when data has many-to-many relationsihps

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

What is a formula to return all the records from a table that satisfy a given criteria?

I have data dealing with teams working on projects using particular rooms for various life-cycle activities. Rooms and their attributes (e.g., square footage, number of network drops) are in one tab, each room appears exactly once. In another tab I have records where separate columns contain: name of a team, room number, project name, life-cycle activity. The relationships in this tab are: One team works on one or more projects, a project uses one or more rooms, a room is used for one or more life-cycle activities.

Users of my workbook--who are mostly excel novices--want to create reports such as:
Given a room number, return list of all projects that use the room.
Given a life-cycle activity, return all the rooms that are used for that activity.

I have a, now blank, page in the workbook in which uses will enter their search criteria.

But I don't know how to write the query to create the desired reports.

(I have a simplified version of my data in an excel 2007 workbook but I'm not seeing a way to attach the file to this Question).

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Have you looked at the Data tab , Filter function? 
After making a tab which consolidates all the data into one Tab.

Comment: Thanks, Ross, for suggestions. I greatly simplified the problem in the question.The data cannot be consolidated into one tab. The data spans many files. Some of the sources have > 24 columns. Also, the rows of the various sources are not distinguished by the same thing. Some tables are rows of room attributes, some are rows of projects. There many thousands of records.

Comment: It sounds like you need to return a variable number of rows , I have done similar by using macros.  One macro does a search and returns a string which says which Sheet and row is of interest (eg Sht1,row2).  It will search only from the previous sht and row. Its all very complex, I generally would use a data base and write queries to return the data into the Excel sheet.

Comment: @user1704475 In this forum you don't **attach** a file.  You can upload your file to some file sharing site (e.g. OneDrive, DropBox) and then insert a hyperlink into your question.  Of course, this requires that you maintain the file on that file sharing site, or others may get lost years from now.

Comment: Link to excel workbook with simplified problem set up: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-TGK-SKvdAgQlQ1emt5RE5keFE

Comment: After examining your worksheet, I agree with @Ross about using a database.  You could do it in Excel; I would create collections (dictionary) of User Defined Objects for Project (with properties of Workgroup, Phase and Location) and for Location (with properties of ID, SqFt, Power, Drops).  You'd then have to work out the logic of iterating through the objects to extract the relevant data depending on your user input.